# Usage of "chance of you being"

Tags: word-usage

When i do my homework, I see this phrase:
"About any chance of you being covered".

I dont know why we use "being covered" here. What structure is this?

Please help :)

Comment: You use "being" to connect "you" and "covered" in the same way you need the verb "be" in connecting a subject and a past participle in a passive voice. "Be" should be changed to "being" because "of" is a preposition.

Answer (score 1):

This is sometimes called a *fused participle*.<sup>[[example](http://www.nytimes.com/1994/02/27/magazine/on-language-defuse-those-participles.html)]</sup>

"You being covered", in a context like this one, is equivalent to "your being covered", and can mean anything from "the fact that you are covered" to "the possibility that you were covered" to "the idea that you would be covered". In your example, "any chance of you being covered" probably means roughly "any chance that you will be covered" (though without more context, it's hard to be sure).